# Конвертация кирилицы в латиницу

Tags: mysql

При вводе текста на кирилице в форму авторизации, можно ли сразу конверировать и записать текст в БД на латинице?

Comment: лучше сделайте это на клиенте. у sql таких готовых функций нет, а менять по одной букве replace слишком большой запрос выйдет

Comment: Можно подробнее?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам действительно необходимо это делать на MySQL, то придется создать таблице перекодирования символов, вроде такой:

```
create table translit(
    rus varchar(1),
    eng varchar(3)
) default charset utf8;

insert into translit(rus, eng) values('А','A'),('Б','B'),('В','V'),('Щ','Sch'),('Я','Ya');
```

после чего для перекодирования одной строки использовать такой запрос:

```
select result
  from (
    select @test:=replace(@test, rus, eng) result, @cnt:=@cnt+1 num
      from translit, (select @cnt:=0, @test:='ЩАВЕЛЬ') s
  ) X
 where num=(select count(1) from translit)
```

[Пример на sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d917a/1)

Но скорее всего гораздо проще будет сделать это на клиентском языке, перед отправкой в БД. Для поиска примера на нужном вам языке в гугле надо ввести "ЯЗЫК транслит" (где "ЯЗЫК" используемый вами язык программирования)

Comment: Проблема в том, что при записе из формы авторизации, всё нормально отображается, но при отправке в телеграм, идёт всё в ???? знаках.

Comment: @0x00 тогда видимо надо решать проблему с кодировкой, а не делать транслитерацию. Но вы спросили как именно сделать транслитерацию средствами MySQL, в данном ответе сказано именно это.