# Только начал изучать sql. Объясните на примере?

Tags: php, mysql

Я хочу произвести замену в строке согласно таблице в базе данных. Таблица в базе данных называется "FindReplace". 3 столбца id, find_what, replace_with.
Накидал для примера:

```
echo '<meta charset="utf8">';
$str = 'Охота в Восточной Пруссии какой-то скучный текст Зимняя рыбалка в Приволжье';
$str = str_replace($find_what, $replace_with, $str);
echo $str;
```

Под переменными $find_what и $replace_with я подразумеваю все данные в соответствующих столбцах. Как правильно производить замену при имеющейся базе?

Кроме того, при изучении MYSQL стали возникать вопросы. Например, заметил, что есть sql, а sqli. В чем разница и что нужно использовать?

Comment: в чем у вас возникает проблема ? подключитесь к mysql сделайте выбору интересующих вас полей, и сделайте замену str_replace($find_what, $replace_with, $str);

Comment: Что то в этом роде https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/861638/194569 разумеется replace в MySQL отлично справляется не только с одиночными буквами, но и с любыми строками

Comment: Задача в общем случае неоднозначная - результат может зависеть от порядка замен (если шаблоны перекрываются). Например, в показанном тексте - если есть замены с шаблонами "рыба" и "балка" - после применения первого второй не может быть применён вне зависимости от порядка. И наоборот - применение одного шаблона может привести к тому, что в тексте появится фрагмент, соответствующий одному из следующих шаблонов, хотя изначально его там не было. Так что надо более тщательно продумать задачу.

Comment: @Akina, там, по задумке, фраза "Охота в Восточной Пруссии" должна стать "В Восточной Пруссии" , а фраза "Зимняя рыбалка в Приволжье" - просто "Зимняя рыбалка".

Comment: @madfan41k, подключиться-то подключился. А вот что дальше... Если бы я не пользовался db, то я бы подготовил массивы: $arr со всеми фразами, которые надо найти; и $arr2 - на что заменить. Причем количество элементов должно совпадать в обоих. Сделал бы preg_replace($arr, $arr2, $str). И все дела. А как вариант с базой провернуть?

Comment: в смысле что дальше ? выберете поля, и верните массив значений с БД

Comment: @madfan41k, как одним запросом закинуть в два массива? Первый - что найти, второй - чем заменить? На форумах приводят разные примеры и там фигурирует функция fetch или схожая с ней.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function pre($var){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($var);
    echo '</pre>';
}

echo '<meta charset="utf8">';

$str = 'Охота в Восточной Пруссии какой-то скучный текст Зимняя рыбалка в Приволжье';
echo $str . '<br>';

$servername = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
$dbname = 'TV';

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $user, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    exit("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = 'SELECT find_what, replace_with FROM FindReplace';
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows){
    $find = array();
    $replace = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $find[] = $row['find_what'];
        $replace[] = $row['replace_with'];
    }
    $str = str_replace($find, $replace, $str);
    echo $str;
}

//Столбец Найти
pre($find);
//Столбец Заменить
pre($replace);
```

Только не пойму в этом контексте цикл while... Чтобы его понять пробовал сделать for, но так и не получилось. Кто-нибудь объясните и/или попробуйте сделать через for, пожалуйста?